# How to create a Marlboro style table with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table that will look like a ["marlboro package"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdiGn.jpg) by using linear-gradient. Something like [image]

```
background:
linear-gradient(-45deg, white,white 25%, red 25%, red), 
linear-gradient( 45deg, white,white 25%, red 25%, red);
```

I'm just a noob so I can't really figure out how to do it.
Can someone help me? consider that the red triangles don't have to reach the bottom border of my table but something like 50% of it

Comment: Could you please show the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML and CSS that you're using, so we can see what you're dealing with, and hopefully be able to suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have the basic idea, but better values for the gradient seem to be `25deg` for the angle and `60%` for the white part.

Something like this

```css
.box{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:
 linear-gradient(-25deg, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, #c60000 60%, #c60000 100%),
 linear-gradient(25deg, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, #c60000 60%, #c60000 100%);
 
 border:10px solid #ccc;
 width:500px;
 height:350px;
 
 font-size:5em;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Marlboro<div>
```